# More than one work in bibliography cited in a single footnote

Tags: footnotes, multiple-citations

Right now I have a Latex thesis which adopts this solution:

```
This guy is a real expert because he's produced these articles on this matter\autocite{article1}\autocite{article2}\autocite{article3}
```

Which produces this result:

> This guy is a real expert because he's produced these articles on this matter<sup>1, 2, 3</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> The guy's first article, also in bibliography
>
> <sup>2</sup> The guy's second article, same
>
> <sup>3</sup> The guy's third article, I mean this is the guy

However, my supervisor asked me to make it look this way:

> This guy is a real expert because he's produced these articles on this matter<sup>1</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> The guy's first article, also in bibliography; the guy's second article; the guy's third article, I mean this is the guy

This is how my document / bibtex is set up:

```
\documentclass[LaM,binding=0.6cm,noexaminfo,fem,twoside]{sapthesis}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=philosophy-verbose,
singletitle=true
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\addbibresource{BibResource.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\printfield{abstract}\finentry}
```

I've looked everywhere but I can't find much: I could create a manual footnote but then would these works be included in the bibliography?
Thank you!

Comment: You are after `\autocite{article1,article2,article3}`. Or if you need separate postnotes, you can use `\autocites`.

Comment: @DavidPurton thank you, your suggestion solved my problem, if you can make an answer out of it I'll choose it as an answer.

Comment: @Vladina you might also like the cheatsheet for biblatex: http://tug.ctan.org/info/biblatex-cheatsheet/biblatex-cheatsheet.pdf